# Tikz: Using non-existent node name works. How?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a puzzle about node names that makes me wonder whether I have misunderstood something. I am trying to draw a diagram with Tikz and have inadvertently used the wrong node name. But it works anyway! How can that be?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\hspace{2cm}
\node (BL)  at  (0,0) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (BR)  at  (3,0) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (TL)  at  (0,3) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (TR)  at  (3,3) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (MBL) at  (1,1) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (MBR) at  (2,1) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (MTL) at  (1,2) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};
\node (MTR) at  (2,2) [circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt]  {};

\draw (BL)--(ML);  % Works, but there is no node ML 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is what I get.

[image: Tikz Diagram]

Any thoughts welcome.

Chris Gordon-Smith

Comment: I got `Package pgf Error: No shape named ML is known. \draw (BL)--(ML)`. Please, add a minimal code so we can reproduce your output.

Comment: You probably have another TikZ picture in your document before this one. The node names survive even after the picture ends and are reused in the next one.

Comment: Or you are loading an old pdf version which contains the right picture.

Comment: It would help if you could post a complete minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`) that reproduces the issue, instead of just the tikzpicture

Comment: Not related to your problem, however never use `\hspace` inside `tikzpicture`!

Comment: Thanks Sigur, Jake and Zarko. Yes, I had a previous Tikz diagram in the file using node ML. Tikz is not C++ !